# Live graph for a C application

Tags: c, graphics, bar-chart, livegraph

I have an application which logs periodically on to a host system it could be on a file or just a console. I would like to use this data to plot a statistical graph for me. I am not sure if I can use the live graph for my application.

If this tool is the right one, may I have an example on integrating the external application with the live graph?

this is livegraph link --> http://www.live-graph.org/download.html

Comment: Where is the link to the tool?

Comment: What kind of statistical graph do you want to plot? LiveGraph seems to only support x/y line graphs, but as long as you write to the file in the correct format it should be able to show your graph.

Comment: i have a datalogger file. it's format is .txt and it has numbers in a line. ( 2,4 5,3 10,1 e.t.c.)
i want to use this file in a program which works it

Comment: The most simple way would be to use an external python script using matplotlib and do a redrawing whenever you update the log file. If you need to do this in C [gnuplot](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/gnuplot_i/index.html) has also a C interface which works also quite well. Just another suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

I think this can be achieved easiest using Python plus [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/). To achieve this there are actually multiple ways: a) integrating the [Python Interpreter](http://docs.python.org/c-api/index.html) directly in your C application, b) printing the data to stdout and piping this to a simple python script that does the actual plotting. In the following I will describe both approaches.

We have the following C application (e.g. `plot.c`). It uses the Python interpreter to interface with matplotlib's plotting functionality. The application is able to plot the data directly (when called like `./plot --plot-data`) and to print the data to `stdout` (when called with any other argument set).

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void initializePlotting() {
  Py_Initialize();
  // load matplotlib for plotting
  PyRun_SimpleString(
    "from matplotlib import pyplot as plt\n"
    "plt.ion()\n"
    "plt.show(block=False)\n"
    );
}

void uninitializePlotting() {
  PyRun_SimpleString("plt.ioff()\nplt.show()");
  Py_Finalize();
}

void plotPoint2d(double x, double y) {
#define CMD_BUF_SIZE 256
  static char command[CMD_BUF_SIZE];
  snprintf(command, CMD_BUF_SIZE, "plt.plot([%f],[%f],'r.')", x, y);
  PyRun_SimpleString(command);
  PyRun_SimpleString("plt.gcf().canvas.flush_events()");
}

double myRandom() {
  double sum = .0;
  int count = 1e4;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    sum = sum + rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
  sum = sum/count;
  return sum;
}

int main (int argc, const char** argv) {
  bool plot = false;
  if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "--plot-data") == 0)
    plot = true;

  if (plot) initializePlotting();

  // generate and plot the data
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    double x = myRandom(), y = myRandom();
    if (plot) plotPoint2d(x,y);
    else printf("%f %f\n", x, y);
  }

  if (plot) uninitializePlotting();
  return 0;
}
```

You can build it like this:

```
$ gcc plot.c -I /usr/include/python2.7 -l python2.7 -o plot
```

And run it like:

```
$ ./plot --plot-data
```

Then it will run for some time plotting red dots onto an axis.

When you choose not to plot the data directly but to print it to the `stdout` you may do the plotting by an external program (e.g. a Python script named `plot.py`) that takes input from `stdin`, i.e. a pipe, and plots the data it gets.
To achieve this call the program like `./plot | python plot.py`, with `plot.py` being similar to:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.show(block=False)
while True:
  # read 2d data point from stdin
  data = [float(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
  assert len(data) == 2, "can only plot 2d data!"
  x,y = data
  # plot the data
  plt.plot([x],[y],'r.')
  plt.gcf().canvas.flush_events()
```

I have tested both approaches on my debian machine. It requires the packages `python2.7` and `python-matplotlib` to be installed.

**EDIT**

I have just seen, that you wanted to plot a bar plot or such thing, this of course is also possible using matplotlib, e.g. a histogram:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.show(block=False)
values = list()
while True:
  data = [float(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
  values.append(data[0])
  plt.clf()
  plt.hist([values])
  plt.gcf().canvas.flush_events()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you only need to write your data in the given format of livegraph and set livegraph up to plot what you want. If wrote small C example which generates random numbers and dumps them together with the time every second. Next, you just attach the livegraph program to the file. That's it.

Playing around with LiveGraph I must say that its use is rather limited. I still would stick to a python script with matplotlib, since you have much more control over how and what is plotted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        FILE *f; 
        gsl_rng *r = NULL;
        const gsl_rng_type *T; 
        int seed = 31456;   
        double rndnum;
        T = gsl_rng_ranlxs2;
        r = gsl_rng_alloc(T);
        gsl_rng_set(r, seed);

        time_t t;
        t = time(NULL);



        f = fopen("test.lgdat", "a");
        fprintf(f, "##;##\n");
        fprintf(f,"@LiveGraph test file.\n");
        fprintf(f,"Time;Dataset number\n");

        for(;;){
                rndnum = gsl_ran_gaussian(r, 1); 
                fprintf(f,"%f;%f\n", (double)t, rndnum);
                sleep(1);
                fflush(f);
                t = time(NULL);
        }   

        gsl_rng_free(r);
        return 0;
}
```

compile with

```
gcc -Wall main.c  `gsl-config --cflags --libs`
```