# Plotting "live" or realtime graph in linux environment using C

Tags: c, gnuplot

I am trying to generate a live graph in C where my y-axis's data is measured realtime/live to debug my robot. Does anyone know how to create a "live" plot? I tried `gnuplot` as below, however the graph is only showing 1 point. I am open to any other method to generate the live chart too. Currently, my raspberry pi is setup as a wifi server, so it is not possible for me to dump all my `x` and `y` axis to the cloud or services online to plot the graph.

I also tried [the suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293775/live-graph-for-a-c-application). Although I had all the library setup properly and compiled successfully but nothing is being displayed.

My data is always 2 float value for the `x` and `y`-axis. Will the `while(1)` cause any problem since I am not able to know the maximum value of my `x`-axis's value?
Thank You.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define DT 0.005  //5ms

int mymillis();
int timeval_subtract(struct timeval *result, struct timeval *t2, struct     timeval *t1);
void plot_graph(FILE* p, float x, float y);

int main() {


int startInt = mymillis();
struct  timeval tvBegin, tvEnd, tvDiff;

gettimeofday(&tvBegin, NULL);

int i = 1;
float x = 0.0;
float y = 0.0;

FILE *f = fopen("file.dat", "w");
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}

FILE *p = popen("gnuplot", "w");
fprintf(p, "plot - with lines\n");

while (1)
{
    startInt = mymillis();
            //Do somethings over here e.g read sensor and filtering


    y = generateX();//Function to generate y-axis data
    x = (float i) * DT;//x-axis


    plot_graph(p, x, y);

    //Each loop should be at least 5ms.
    while (mymillis() - startInt < (DT * 1000))
    {
        usleep(100);
    }

    i++;
}

return 0;
}

int mymillis()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec) / 1000;
}

int timeval_subtract(struct timeval *result, struct timeval *t2, struct timeval *t1)
{
    long int diff = (t2->tv_usec + 1000000 * t2->tv_sec) - (t1->tv_usec + 1000000 * t1->tv_sec);
    result->tv_sec = diff / 1000000;
    result->tv_usec = diff % 1000000;
    return (diff<0);
}

void plot_graph(FILE *p, float x, float y) {

    fprintf(p,"plot '-'\n");
    fprintf(p, "%f %f\n", x, y); // plot `a` points
    fprintf(p,"e\n");    // finally, e
    fflush(p);   // flush the pipe to update the plot

}
```

Comment: If it must not all be in C, have a look at https://github.com/dkogan/feedgnuplot

Comment: It looks like your send gnuplot a `plot` command with only a single (x,y) pair, so it's not surprising that gnuplot only shows a single point. If you want a time trace you will have to accumulate the date for the time period of interest; gnuplot won't do that for you. You could use an array or write the data to a file on disk.

Comment: Hi all, I am the original poster, I can't login to my account. Hence,  using this account. Christoph I look at the link but is not really sure how to integrate it into my program. I will take a look again.

@user8153 I followed your advice and it work. However, it is very slow as it is replotting the graph every iteration. the code I used is from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521209/making-c-code-plot-a-graph-automatically
I wanted to edit my post but I am not able to login. If you know how to make it fast let me know. Anyone else with other solution, let me know too. Thanks.